# How to force an Emacs tramp time out?

Tags: emacs, tramp

I use TRAMP a lot with emacs.  However, sometimes a server goes down and tramp sits waiting for a timeout.  Usually it's after doing a `C-x-f` in ido-mode to open a new file.  I have to wait an annoyingly long amount of time.  Is there an easy way to tell TRAMP to timeout and let ido-mode continue.  I try `C-g` and the option to open a file never happens.

Comment: Whether `C-g` works in this situation may depend on your operating system (and on some “exotic” (i.e. non-unix), platforms, how Emacs was compiled, and perhaps even how the ssh or other helper program was compiled).

Comment: Ah.  I'm using cygwin's emacs and cygwin's scp.

Answer (score 2):

In thoses (frequent) cases when tramp stalls, I just halt the process with `C-g`, kill the tramp buffer and I can then save the file.

```
M-x kill-buffer RET *tramp.*
```

Comment: Indeed; killing the tramp buffer for the relevant connection is a useful general approach to fixing tramp issues. (I'm not sure it's the best solution to something which is happening really frequently, but it's certainly a good one to keep in mind.)

Comment: When I say frequently, what I really mean is that when I return to edit a tramp-opened file after say, more than an hour (witch is not that frequent) I'm pretty sure that tramp is deep asleep. Ever since I discovered that C-g & killing the tramp buffer works, my relationship with emacs has improved. What prevented you to upvote my answer BTW ?

Comment: I didn't upvote because it didn't seem directly relevant to the question -- killing the tramp buffer can be very useful, but it can't bring a remote server back to life.

Answer (score 1):

I found one hint that can limit the painful wait to 5 seconds.  Add this line to .ssh/config:

```
Host *
     ServerAliveInterval 5
```

However, after five seconds, you still can't choose a file.  So, when it fails just do a `C-x b` to a buffer that's not opened on the downed server and `C-x-f` from there will not take forever.

Answer (score 0):

I don't face such timeout situation though I frequently use TRAMP.  Try something like

```
(defun tramp-find-file-timeout ()
  (when tramp
    (with-timeout (4)
      (keyboard-quit))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'tramp-find-file-timeout)
```

I used [this](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/LEGAo54re8XFNLM3yJMN) and [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/TrampMode) to make this suggestion.  something better than `keyboard-quit` could work for you.

Comment: Oh, this looks like it would work, but it fails for some reason.  Bummer!