# How to interrupt tramp from reading a big file

Tags: emacs, tramp

Some time ago I opened a file via tramp. That is, effectively via ssh/scp.  It still is not finished and I would like to stop the reading.  Yet <kbd>C-g</kbd> does not work. Apart from killing emacs (which seems quite unethical to me, it also destroys my M-x shell s), do I have any other option to stop the loading?

Note that the server does not hang. And I do not want any timeouts [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371255/how-to-force-an-emacs-tramp-time-out).

Comment: Unless your shells are way more advanced than any I've ever used or heard of destroying them is hardly unethical.  Impractical, bothersome, excessively forceful, all sorts of adjectives spring to mind.  But not unethical; you're destroying a simple computer process, not a sentient entity.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: agreed, I thought the "also" makes this clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can find the corresponding `ssh` / `scp` process ID, you can kill just that.

Comment: Thank you! My emacs is still alive!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty bonus; much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If neither <kbd>C-g</kbd> nor <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> are interrupting, but Emacs is still responding to <kbd>M-x</kbd> commands, you can kill the connection or the whole buffer.

[The TRAMP manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Cleanup-remote-connections.html#Cleanup-remote-connections) suggests that the following <kbd>M-x</kbd> commands may be of interest:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tramp-cleanup-this-connection`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tramp-cleanup-all-buffers`